# Using Aggregate and Cbind- NA issue?

Tags: r, aggregate, na, cbind

I am using `cbind` to find the mean of 3 different columns. However I get different answers for the means when I do:

```
  DFNEW <- aggregate(cbind(X1, X2, X3)~Y, DF, FUN=mean)
```

vs

```
  DFNEW <- aggregate(cbind(X1, X2)~Y, DF, FUN=mean)
```

The means of X1 and X2 are different when I run command 1 and when I run command 2. X1, X2, and X3 all have different numbers of NA arguments- is that the reason? Part of this may also be that I'm not entirely sure what `cbind` is doing in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the reason why you are getting different result is because by default, `na.action=na.omit` for the `formula` interface.  So, the rows with `NA`s are omitted and not used for the calculation of `mean`.  When we use different combinations of columns, different rows could be deleted based on the occurrence of `NA`.  By specifying `na.action=NULL`, the rows will not get deleted and we can remove the `NA` values while calculating the `mean` by using the argument `na.rm=TRUE` in the `mean` function.

```
  aggregate(cbind(X1, X2)~Y, DF, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
   #Y       X1       X2
   #1 A 3.625000 6.375000
   #2 B 3.000000 6.750000
   #3 C 4.142857 7.166667

  aggregate(cbind(X1, X2, X3)~Y, DF, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
  #  Y       X1       X2       X3
  #1 A 3.625000 6.375000 2.875000
  #2 B 3.000000 6.750000 1.500000
  #3 C 4.142857 7.166667 1.333333
```

The results we get from the above will be the same below i.e. without using the `formula` interface

```
aggregate(DF[,c("X1", "X2")], list(Y=DF[,"Y"]), FUN= mean, na.rm=TRUE)
#  Y       X1       X2
# 1 A 3.625000 6.375000
# 2 B 3.000000 6.750000
# 3 C 4.142857 7.166667


aggregate(DF[,c("X1", "X2", "X3")], list(Y=DF[,"Y"]), FUN= mean, na.rm=TRUE)
#  Y       X1       X2       X3
#1 A 3.625000 6.375000 2.875000
#2 B 3.000000 6.750000 1.500000
#3 C 4.142857 7.166667 1.333333
```

If you want some alternatives, you could use `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
  DF %>% 
     group_by(Y) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
  # Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

  #  Y       X1       X2       X3
  #1 A 3.625000 6.375000 2.875000
  #2 B 3.000000 6.750000 1.500000
  #3 C 4.142857 7.166667 1.333333

   DF %>% 
      group_by(Y) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), X1, X2)
   #Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

   #  Y       X1       X2
   #1 A 3.625000 6.375000
   #2 B 3.000000 6.750000
   #3 C 4.142857 7.166667
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(X1=sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace=TRUE), 
    X2= sample(c(NA, 1:10), 25, replace=TRUE), X3= sample(c(NA,0:5), 25, 
    replace=TRUE), Y=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 25, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Do you know why cbind was giving those different averages though?

Comment: @ichordia91 As I mentioned in the description, for the formula method, `na.action=na.omit` is removing different rows whenever there is a `NA` in a row. So, when you take the mean, depending on whether a row is lost or not, the means will be different.

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of open source is diversity and array of tools available. Quite a fun. Here is a `data.table` alternative for your reference.  Use @akrun's data.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=T), by=Y]
#    Y       X1       X2       X3
# 1: C 4.142857 7.166667 1.333333
# 2: A 3.625000 6.375000 2.875000
# 3: B 3.000000 6.750000 1.500000

setDT(DF)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=T), by=Y, .SDcols=1:2]
#   Y       X1       X2
# 1: C 4.142857 7.166667
# 2: A 3.625000 6.375000
# 3: B 3.000000 6.750000
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use split command:

```
> sapply(split(DF, DF$Y), function(x) sapply(x[1:3], mean, na.rm=T))
       A    B        C
X1 3.625 3.00 4.142857
X2 6.375 6.75 7.166667
X3 2.875 1.50 1.333333
```

(Using @akrun's data)